# Access local file in a WebView

Tags: android, webview

My native app includes a WebView, and the WebView loads a web page off web. For example, the html is loaded from

http://dongshengcn.com/test.html

It seems any page loaded from web (instead of local) can not load any file from local device.

My question is:

Is it possible for a http://dongsheng.com/test.html loaded to a webview (as part of native app) to access file on local device?

Comment: post your code and where you put file ?

Comment: This may be a security mechanism.  I tried a file:///mnt/sdcard/some.jpg link on a test webpage, and found it would not even attempt to load when clicked on an android device. However, if I long pressed the link and selected 'open' from the popup menu, then the referenced local image actually would open.  Tried it with an html file too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to try:

1. To use local files you need to place them in your project's assets folder and invoke them using URLs such as file:///android_asset/. For example, if you add mypage.html in your assets folder, then you can invoke it in the webview with file:///android_asset/mypage.html.
2. Check to make sure that you have the appropriate webview permissions in your Manifest. For the webview to work correctly, you need:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
3. Take a look at the following app on Github, which as a bonus also fixes a couple of bugs with the webview in Honeycomb and ICS. It is a full example on how to use the webview with local files:
   https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/WebViewIssue17535FixDemo

EDIT: Addendum after question clarification:

Yes, it is possible to load a local page from the web, but you must use a trick to bypass the browser's security measures.

Replace the file://android_asset/ portion of the URLs with a custom scheme (e.g. file///android_asset/mypage.html becomes myscheme:///mypage.html), and place these custom scheme URLs in your page. Implement WebViewClient's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, check if the URL begins with the custom scheme and if so redirect to the local page using webview.loadUrl.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()  
    {  
        @Override  
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("myscheme://"))  
            {  
                String newUrl = url.replace("myscheme://", "file://android_asset/");  
                mWebView.loadUrl(newUrl);  
                return true;  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Theo. I clarified my question a little bit.

Comment: Please see my revised response above.