# Android WebView Ajax GET inner text file error

Tags: android, ajax, webview

In my case I am trying to read a text file by Ajax from within a WebView of an Android app.
This is a JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        var response = data;
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Response error: " + e.status);
    }
});
```

I tried it in different ways - synchronous and asynchronous, XmlHTTP and $.ajax and always e.status = 0;

As to Android's permissions, here they are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().getAllowFileAccess();
webView.getSettings().getAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs();
webView.getSettings().getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs();
webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().getAllowContentAccess();
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

What kind of problem this is?

Comment: Why don't you refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620417/access-local-file-in-a-webview

Comment: nil, I don't refer to that post because it's about getting files from a native part of a project, not from within a WebView by JS.