# How to get file path of files located in resources

Tags: android, html, android-resources, android-assets

I am using `WebView` and applying some styling to `WebView`'s text. My fonts are located in the `res/font` folder right now and I am using those fonts to apply custom font. I creating my own html and applying font like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family:MyFont; 
        src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/open_sans_regular.ttf")}
        body {font-family: MyFont;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    //MY CONTENT GOES HERE

    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is working fine. But my problem is this solution making me **copy font inside `res/font` to `assets` folder**. Because I have to reference font like this 
`file:///android_asset/fonts/open_sans_regular.ttf`. Not only this copying is bad practise but also increasing the size of my apk.

My quesion is/are:

1. How can I access file path (of the font that is located in the `res/fonts`) and use it instead of this `file:///android_asset/fonts/open_sans_regular.ttf` so that I do not have to copy my fonts?
2. You might probably suggest why not move those font completely to `assets` folder. I cannot do this because those fonts are refernced in my `styles`. Like this:

```
 <style name="Font.OpenSans.Light">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans_regular</item>
 </style>
```

As you can see, removing those `fonts` will cause issues in my `styles`. May be, I can move the fonts to `assets` folder and access them from `styles`? Is this even possible?

Any suggestios would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620417/access-local-file-in-a-webview

Comment: @MohammedAquibAzad did not help

Comment: `My fonts are located in the res/font folder` Ok. But where is your html file resided?

Comment: @blackapps Html file does not exist. It is just `String`.

Comment: Untested: You can indicate a baseurl in the html. To getExternalFilesDir() for example. And copy the fonts from res/raw to it. Then the paths relative.