# How can I use <img> with a local image on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, image

Using `<img>` with the `src`, a local file works fine on a PC. But on Android 7 it doesn't get displayed; instead a no photo icon is displayed. How can I solve this?

```
<img src="photo.png">
```

(The `photo.png` is placed in the same folder as the `.html` file.)

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027701/loading-existing-html-file-with-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the path of the photo:

```
<img sc = " xxxpathxxx/"photo.png">
```

Else, make a separate image folder and call it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is [how Webview works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620417/access-local-file-in-a-webview) with local files. File paths aren't the same as your PC Google Chrome paths where you can drag an HTML file to the browser and have it be loaded in a certain path, and because of that photo.png doesn't direct anywhere.

Instead, you need to use the [file:// schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to access local files. Regardless of whether photo.png is local or an Internet resource, you'll need to use photo.png's absolute path, e.g.:

```
http://localhost/path/to/photo.png
http://www.mywebsite.com/path/to/photo.png
file://data/local/tmp/photo.png
```